# How to give justifications on Huawei App rejection

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

In the Huawei app gallery store, my uploaded Huawei application has been rejected. I would like to resubmit my application with a justification. I would like to know on which section I need to provide justification that the error you are pointing is not an error, but an unused feature that is available to only a limited number of users.